# Joomla 2.5 URL_rewrite activated - Site can be accessed with and without index.php

Tags: php, .htaccess, joomla, joomla2.5

I have activated the URL_rewrite in my Joomla 2.5 and have also renamed the .htaccess as was described.

Everything works well. Unfortunately I couldn't find any answer for the following question on the web.

My site can be accessed now through both links:

```
www.mysite.com/index.php/category
```

And

```
www.mysite.com/category
```

So basically all links that are already available on the web which are including /index.php/ to our site are not forwarded to the site without index.php.

I can imagine that this could cause the problem with duplicate content.

How can I solve this or did I do anything wrong as I would expect from Joomla this would work out of the box?

Answer (score 0):

You could add the folowing **.htaccess** rule right after `RewriteEngine On`.

```
RewriteRule ^index.php/(.*)$ /$1 [L,R=301]
```

Hope this helps